# Jquery Ajax preloader only onclick with several Ajax requests an phps

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am facing the following problem. I have got an index.php that contains a form. There are several AJAX-requests which point to different phps that dynamically load further form elements, e.g. when the option of a selectbox is changed.

The form itself contains a click-button which points to a php performing an AJAX-Request when being clicked. While waiting for the php to respond to the Ajax-Request, the preloader icon shall appear.

Everything works fine except:

When I change the select box the preloader icon appears which is wrong. But when I click the button of the form, the preloader icon does not appear but it shall appear.

This is my code at the start of the index php. As I am not a Jquery expert, does anyone have a hint for me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank yo very much in advance for your help!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(){
$.post("calculate.php", $("#calculate").serialize(),  function(response) {   
$('#success').html(response);
});
return false;
});
});
</script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#showcontentonchange').change(function(){
$.post("showcontentonchange.php", $("#showcontentonchange").serialize(),  function(response) {   
$('#successshowcontentonchange').html(response);
});
return false;
});
});
</script>


<script>
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
beforeSend: function() {
$('#preloader').html('&nbsp;<img src="preloader.gif" style="position:relative;left:50%;margin-left:-64px;margin-top:5px;z-index:1;">')
},
complete: function(){
$('#preloader').html('')
},
success: function() {
$('#preloader').html('')    
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you paste and html ?

Comment: Could you please format your code with a proper indentations.